# Rails 4: How to exclude a CSS file from a specific view?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can one exclude a specific CSS file (custom.css.scss) from a specific view (home.html.erb)?

Following scenario. My rails app is made up of the actual web application for which one has to sign in for to see it and the outward facing landing page.

The CSS for the web application lives inside a file called `custom.css.scss`.

For the landing page I created a new CSS file called `static_pages.css.scss`.

Now, the problem obviously is that Rails pulls in all stylesheets and applies them to all views:

`*= require_tree .
 *= require_self`

However, now my landing page is being messed up by the custom.css.scss file which contains the app-specific CSS and vice-versa.

Since my landing page is simply a one-pager, the ideal solution would be to simply exclude `custom.css.scss` from my home.html.erb file which represents the landing page.

How can I achieve this?

I have found various topics on this problem for but can't make sense of it. Some look to simply inject, some look to exclude.

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Write the HTML on your homepage in such a way that the custom CSS doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

Find this kind of line in your template:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

It actually does the magic, both of `custom` and `static` css was included to application.css

Excluding something is weird, for css we usually use selector to identify which elements will be effect to.

My suggestion to achieve your case is:

1. Add specific class/id which identifies controller/action
   For example, I add this kind of code to my layout template:

`<body id="<%= controller_name %>_body">`

So every view now has `id` for its body

2. Modify custom css to apply for all, except landing page. For example my landing page has body's id: `landing_page_body`

In `custom.css.scss`

```
body:not(#landing_page_body) {
  // My css here apply for all except for #landing_page_body
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to include a specific stylesheet on a per-page basis, you'll have to create & compile it separately, calling it as you need:

```
#config/initializers/assets.rb

#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
/* 
  *= require_tree .
  *= require self
  *= stub custom
*/

#app/assets/stylsheets/custom.css
...
```

This would allow you to specify when you're going to call the stylesheet:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application, (:custom if controller_name != "landing") %>
```

This will only load the `custom` stylesheet if you're not using the landing controller.